# Where is the jQuery template documentation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I cannot find the jQuery [template documentation](https://freejquery.com/?s=template%20documentation) or the plugin from the jQuery site. 
Can anyone tell where to locate them?
I tried searching, but I couldn't find the documentation. 
It seems the jQuery Plugin site is broken.

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: @BNL is it not in active development ? is this the same microsoft contribution to the jQuery ? or is it different ? I saw a blog post from jQuery blog that says they are officially supporting it and the data linking plugin. what is going on ?

Comment: @MattBall I am new to this whole template thing, so I looked up and found that the jQuery-templates has official support from jQuery foundation and started looking for it... but I couldn't find it. I have no idea what should I use!!! Can you recommend any other template libraries ?

Comment: @CodeWeed it is the same thing. the blog you read is old. nothing ever came of it. a big disappointment imho.

Comment: I'd look at knockout.js as an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery template is not maintained now. So the plugin has been removed from jquery plugin repository. Hence documentation is also gone. I could only find the below links for documentation. They are not perfect, but still very helpful.

1. https://github.com/jquery-orphans/jquery-tmpl
2. https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl

KanbanSolutions has forked the project and fixed some bugs. But they have changed some syntax.
But you can refer to this documentation because functionality of Kanban custom jquery template and original jquery template is same.

For example 
Documentation for `each` for Kanban custom jquery template

```
{%each( index, value ) collection %}
```

Used to iterate over a data array, and render the content between the opening and closing template tags once for each data item.

Hence, 
Documentation for `each` for original jquery template

```
{{each( index, value ) collection }}
```

Used to iterate over a data array, and render the content between the opening and closing template tags once for each data item.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it here http://web.archive.org/web/20120920065217/http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ (followed from GitHub wiki - https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/wiki)

Comment: jquery tmpl not supported long time bitter to use another one. for example http://underscorejs.org/#template